# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.getConnectTimeout()I

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

i am trying to send message via Firebase admin sdk java, but it shows noSuchMethodError.

```
public void sendMulticast() {
    // [START send_multicast]
    // Create a list containing up to 100 registration tokens.
    // These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
    List<String> registrationTokens = Arrays.asList(
            "du7LouAvvCM:APA91bHpQY1ieATOCfQLaZbHQFGYV4FcDzwWFuZeKyLqhLZRELsdGTymL5NDcCE-1YzYhoyuX18_J1_a0eB2"
    );

    MulticastMessage message = MulticastMessage.builder()
            .putData("score", "850")
            .putData("time", "2:45")
            .addAllTokens(registrationTokens)
            .build();
    BatchResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendMulticast(message);
    } catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // See the BatchResponse reference documentation
    // for the contents of response.
    System.out.println(response.getSuccessCount() + " messages were sent successfully");
    // [END send_multicast]
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.getConnectTimeout()I
    at com.google.firebase.internal.FirebaseRequestInitializer$TimeoutInitializer.(FirebaseRequestInitializer.java:65)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.FirebaseRequestInitializer.(FirebaseRequestInitializer.java:45)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.ApiClientUtils.newAuthorizedRequestFactory(ApiClientUtils.java:47)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.fromApp(FirebaseMessagingClientImpl.java:235)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$6.get(FirebaseMessaging.java:425)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging$6.get(FirebaseMessaging.java:422)
    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$MemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:120)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.getMessagingClient(FirebaseMessaging.java:300)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendAllOp(FirebaseMessaging.java:289)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendAll(FirebaseMessaging.java:183)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendMulticast(FirebaseMessaging.java:252)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.sendMulticast(FirebaseMessaging.java:227)
    at SendFirebaseNotifications.sendMulticast(SendFirebaseNotifications.java:26)
    at Main.main(Main.java:101)

Comment: Do you have an older version of the SDK or the Firebase Android SDK in the classpath?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka No. I have updated to the latest SDK Version.

Comment: It is some kind of a classloading issue. My guess is you somehow have multiple versions of `FirebaseOptions` in your classpath. And of those versions is either really old or from the Android SDK. Try calling `getConnectTimeout() directly on `FirebaseOptions` in an IDE and what happens.

Comment: I checked the classpath. It has only latest version of firebase admin SDK. And
getConnecetTimeout() is available in FirebaseOptions when called separately.